# replace column and get ltrim of the column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to replace an column in an dataframe. need to get the scala 
 syntax code for this
Controlling_Area = CC2
Hierarchy_Name = CC2HIDNE

Need to write as  :  HIDENE
ie: remove the Controlling_Area present in Hierarchy_Name .

```
val dfPC = ReadLatest("/Full", "parquet")
.select(
LRTIM(   REPLACE(col("Hierarchy_Name"),col("Controlling_Area"),"") ),
Col(ColumnN),
Col(ColumnO)
)
```

```
notebook:3: error: not found: value REPLACE
   REPLACE(col("Hierarchy_Name"),col("Controlling_Area"),"")
   ^
```

Expecting to get the LTRIM and replace code in scala

Answer (score 0):

You can use withColumnRenamed to achieve that:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions    
val dfPC = ReadLatest("/Full", "parquet")
                     .withColumnRenamed("Hierarchy_Name","Controlling_Area")
                     .withColumn("Controlling_Area",ltrim(col("Controlling_Area")))
```

Comment: can i have is as a part of select query since i have many columns as part of the sql

Comment: SAMPLE CODE
val dfPC = ReadLatest(s"/Full", "parquet")
.where("Hierarchy_Text = 'SYSTEM'")
.select(  
col("Controlling_Area"),REPLACE(col("Hierarchy_Name"),col("Controlling_Area"),"") , col(""))